# Is it possible to write tests for Cross origin website with Selenium Core

Tags: javascript, grails, testing, selenium, cross-domain

I have implemented Selenium Core for writing tests for a web application and its worked well when included into the project.

But Now the requirement is to keep the test cases separate from the project so the condition has become something like below example.

For example :

I am running a application having Selenium core configured in it on my local system and i have to test a site hosted on "www.example.com"

I encountered cross origin issues like

```
"Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame."
```

I am using Selenium plugin in Grails Application for doing this.

i have came across

> open ( url )
>       Opens an URL in the test frame. This accepts both relative and absolute URLs. The "open" command waits for the page to load before proceeding, ie. the "AndWait" suffix is implicit. Note: The URL must be on the same domain as the runner HTML due to security restrictions in the browser (Same Origin Policy). If you need to open an URL on another domain, use the Selenium Server to start a new browser session on that domain.

Please provide me steps on how to do this as i am new to selenium

```
"If you need to open an URL on another domain, use the Selenium Server to start a new browser session on that domain."
```

Is there some work around for doing this as i have invested a lot of time in creating test in Selenium core and they worked well when are in same application.

Please suggest me about the feasibility of doing this or some other solution.

Comment: What do you mean under "requirement is to keep the test cases separate from the project". Now you have two projects: the original without tests and the new project with tests only and without sources? Did you saved project structure in the second? How did you separate it?

Comment: @wwarlock: yes this is true "Now you have two projects: the original without tests and the new project with tests only and without sources " i have put the test cases into a separate project.

Comment: How do you run tests now? From the same machine where you started the server? And how do you run tests before? Did you changed any test/code while separating project?

Comment: Hm, I've tried to google. Looks like that is not Grails problem. People catched it just with Selenium.

Comment: I don't think it will be helpful but I recommend you to try test with `Geb` plugin. That is yet one abstraction layer over Selenium. And maybe it has bug fix for iFrames.